# How to copy a list item's content text on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of items in a HTML page. I need to make the items as links. When a user clicks any of them, I should be able to copy its content text and pass it to a function, e.g. `alert(the_value_of_selected_list_item)`.

Here is my attempt so for:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
}
#leftsideMenu ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed lightgray;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

#leftsideMenu ul li a {
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

#leftsideMenu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(238, 224, 144);
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftsideMenu">
  <h3> Data</h3>
  <ul style="list-style-type:none">
      <li><a href="#">this is first list item</a></li>    
      <li><a href="#">this is second list item</a></li>  
      <li><a href="#">this is third list item</a></li>          

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `li` elements don't have "value". What exactly are you expecting to get as a "value" of the list item? A reference to the listitem itself? A reference to the link it contains? A string presentation of the li/a element? The text in the link? Something else?

Comment: the text in the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```js
function doSomthing(data){
alert(data.innerText)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" class="no-js">

<head>
    <title> Demo</title>
    <style>
        h1 {
          text-align: center;
        }
        
        h2 {
          text-align: left;
        }
        #leftsideMenu ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed lightgray;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

#leftsideMenu ul li a {
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

#leftsideMenu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(238, 224, 144);
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}        
    </style>

    
</head>
<body>

    <div id="leftsideMenu">
       
    <h3> Data</h3>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <li><a onclick="doSomthing(this)"  href="javascript:void(0)">this is first list item</a></li>    
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">this is second list item</a></li>  
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">this is third list item</a></li>          
 
    </ul>  
    


    
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You coud do it this way:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll("#leftsideMenu a");
links.forEach(l=> l.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(l.textContent)
}))
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
}
#leftsideMenu ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed lightgray;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

#leftsideMenu ul li a {
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

#leftsideMenu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(238, 224, 144);
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftsideMenu">
  <h3> Data</h3>
  <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li><a href="#">this is first list item</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">this is second list item</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">this is third list item</a></li>          
  </ul>
<div>
```